# Что такое принцип MVS ( не MVC)?

Tags: c#, python, c++, qt, pyqt5

Что такое принцип `MVS` ( не `MVC`)? Есть ли вообще такое?
может принцип построения событийной модели приложения?

Comment: Поиск по MVS выдает что-то совсем левое. Где вы прочитали или услышали этот термин, и в каком контексте?

Comment: Было одно задание создать приложение по этому принципу MVS, также есть связанные с этим принципом понятия: механизм сообщений и функция обратного вызова.

Comment: Может опечатка в задании?

Comment: Привет выдающему вам задание :) 
`MVS - Multiple Virtual Storage` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVS . 
`MVC - Model  View Controller`  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html